# Using a div instead of tables how can I lock the 1st header row

Tags: jquery, html, tablerow

What I want to do is to have a set of divs that are doing a table using display:table, display:table-row, etc.  All of this table is contained inside of another div container that has scrollbars on it.  When I scroll this outside container I want the first row to scroll and stay visible

If I have the following html

```
<div class="tableContainer">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divRow headerRow">
            <div class="divCell header">A</div>
            <div class="divCell header">B</div>
            <div class="divCell header">C</div>
            <div class="divCell header">D</div>
            <div class="divCell header">E</div>
            <div class="divCell header">F</div>
            <div class="divCell header">G</div>
            <div class="divCell header">H</div>
        </div>

        <div class="divRow">
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
            <div class="divCell">something</div>
       </div>

      <!--repeat above row a bunch of times to make the scrollbar appear-->  
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
.tableContainer {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;    
}

.divTable {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}

.divRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.headerRow {
    display: table-row;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
}

.divCell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px;
}

.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and the following JQuery script

```
    $('.tableContainer').scroll(function() {
        $('.headerRow').css('top', $('.tableContainer').scrollTop() + 'px');
    });
```

If I run the above stuff I can see the top changing for the headerRow, but visibly it never moves, it just stays at the top of the table and scrolls out of view.  The only way that I can get it to scroll down is if I change the headerRow class to be positioned absolutely, but if I do that then it breaks the column-widths and the header row is not the same column widths as the detail rows.

Comment: This would work the same way you would do it with a table. You would have to calculate the column widths and apply them to the header row. Is there a reason you're using divs instead of a table? just don't like tables?

Comment: There is a bunch of other things that I would like to do with these and want them to be in divs for ease of use for the other things that I want.

Comment: Basically place your "table tbody" inside of a scrollable div with a set height so that it scrolls, but keep your "table thead" outside of that scrollable div. you would then need to calculate the column widths and apply them to the "table thead" columns.

Comment: Why would you need to use a div for a tabular data? Is there any constraint in using tables?

Comment: There are other solutions to have fixed header.. sometime back I wrote a plugin for fixed header and columns.. nothing fancy.. check this demo page http://meetselva.github.com/fixed-table-rows-cols/ and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understod your problem exactly then here is what you can try ...

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){


 $('.tableContainer').scroll(function() {
    $('.headerRow')
          .stop()
          .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a fixed width it is very simple.
Have a look at this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
}
.tableContainer {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.divTable {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
}
.divRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.headerRow {
    width: 600px;
    display: table-row;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.divCell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 75px;
}
.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you want a non-fixed width, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cellWidth = $(".divCell").css("width");
    var tableWidth = $(".divRow").css("width");
    $(".headerRow").css({
        "width": tableWidth,
        "position": "fixed"
    }).find(".divCell").css("width", cellWidth);
});
```

Example at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakschu/WWCeL/).
It offers a nice fallback if there is no JS support: the header stays in the table.